# Ubuntu JSON API script to search IPs

Tags: json, api, ubuntu

I'm after firstly formatting a curl JSON API link in Ubuntu, as you can see in my picture, on the website JSON is formatted correctly, via Ubuntu Its just a bunch of word-wrapped code.

I tried using `| jq` at the end but that didn't work like so

```
curl https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/51.38.41.14/json? 
key=my_key_here&days=7&verbose | jq
```

(not including my API key) (51.38.41.14) Is a spammer IP

Once this is figured out I would then want to script it so I run an alias called IPDB that asks me the IP and displays the curl address API request

Any guidance would be apprecaited

[image]

Comment: My  next part to this script is for it to ask for an IP, Is this possible?

Comment: Ok figured how to format, damn missed the quotes :)
curl -s 'https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/51.38.41.14/json?key=xFXEqxYArUg2JHoO35gMrXtc46pLoSc3J9yg2rVK&days=7&verbose' | jq

Answer (score 0):

And again I figured it out for myself, no Idea why I joined today seen as I answered all my own questions :)
It might be helpful to someone in the future.

Make a text file and call it abuse.sh and copy the below text into it, then run the script and it will ask for a IP

```
echo Please enter IP to search
read -p 'IPaddress: ' IP
echo curl -s https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/$IP/json?key=your_key_here=7&verbose' | jq
```

I have taken my API key out, but you can get a free one from their website.

This script is for IP checking to see if the IP Is an abuser(spammer, hacker etc). I work for an ISP and wanted to automate how to check for IPs besides using good ole mxtoolbox.